# Unlimited integer value for JSON-LD schema

Tags: schema, json-ld

How would you write an AggregateOffer schema JSON-LD to display an unlimited offerCount parameter?

https://schema.org/offerCount

Comment: Anyone knows how to please?

Comment: Could you explain the scenario this is for?